# Oracle and multiple JSONs

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get list of 'ids' in oracle if data is like this one?

```
{'id': 360006648459, 'value': None
},
{'id': 360002406974, 'value': None
},
{'id': 360003271394, 'value': None
},
{'id': 360020289239, 'value': None
}
...
```

I'm getting (null) when trying this which is expected:

```
SELECT json_query(FIELD, '$.id')
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Have a look at json_table

Answer (score 0):

```
select json_value(q'~{'id': 360006648459, 'value': None}~', '$.id') from dual ;
```

will return the id

```
select json_query(q'~{'id': 360006648459, 'value': None}~', '$.id' with wrapper) from dual ;
```

will return the id wrapped into an array

Comment: Both ways it gets only one id. How to get the list of all of 'em?

Comment: select json_value(FIELD, '$.id') from TABLE ;
if each FIELD contains 1 record, if FIELD contains all the records as you posted above: this is not valid JSON.

Comment: Thank you, yes it is not valid.

Comment: add some [ ] to the field so it becomes an array

Comment: @nbk, can you please show an example of the code?

Comment: see the answer of selvar, but MT0 makes a good point None is not json compatible

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a valid json like `'{"id": 360006648459, "value": "None"},{"id": 360002406974, "value": "None"},{"id": 360003271394, "value": "None"},{"id": 360020289239, "value": "None"}'`

Then you can get your desired output using `json_table`

```
select id
from mytable, json_table(concat(concat('[', FIELD),']'), '$[*]' columns(id path '$.id')) t
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZWty2y3I)

Comment: The OP does not have `"None"`. They have `None`, which is not valid JSON.

Comment: you could add a replace and exchange all none to something more json compatible, but i thing none is only a abbreviation of the real data

Answer (score 0):

If you have the non-JSON sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (field) AS
SELECT q'|{'id': 360006648459, 'value': None
},
{'id': 360002406974, 'value': None
},
{'id': 360003271394, 'value': None
},
{'id': 360020289239, 'value': None
}|' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can try converting it to valid JSON by wrapping it in array `[]` brackets and changing `None` to `null` and then you can use a JSON parser:

```sql
select j.id
from   table_name
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         '[' || REPLACE( field, 'None', 'null') || ']',
         '$[*]'
         COLUMNS (
           id path '$.id'
         )
       ) j;
```

*Note: This assumes that the sub-string `None` will only ever appear in the context where it means a `null` value; if it can appear in other contexts then you may not be able to use this approach.*

*Note 2: Technically, single quotes around object keys is not valid JSON; however, Oracle will parse them as if they were valid quotes. To convert to the strict JSON format you would need `'[' || REPLACE( REPLACE( field, 'None', 'null'), '''', '"') || ']'`.*

Which outputs:

| ID |
| --- |
| 360006648459 |
| 360002406974 |
| 360003271394 |
| 360020289239 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EP-6bdMT)